# Don't look back, crazy clown

Tags: word, wordplay, no-computers, river-crossing, word-ladder

Start with these two words

```
INSANE                RETROSPECT
```

and see if you can get them to exchange places by transferring one letter at a time.  With each transfer, you may also rearrange (anagram) each word in any way you choose.  However, each side must always remain a valid English word.

You are finished when you have reached

```
RETROSPECT            INSANE
```

All the intermediate words should be fairly common, so you shouldn't have to reach for your dictionary.  There is one word along the way which might seem a little unfamiliar to some, so I will give it to everyone as a guidepost:  [INTERCASTE](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/intercaste).

Here is an unrelated example just to illustrate the movement:

```
MAGISTRATE          DENSER
    |     .           |
    |       .         |
    |         I       |
    |           .     |
    v             .   v
STRATAGEM           DENIERS
    |     .           |
    |       .         |
    |         T       |
    |           .     |
    v             .   v
MEGASTAR            RESIDENT
    |             .   |
    |           .     |
    |         N       |
    |       .         |
    v     .           v
MAGNETARS           DIETERS 
    |     .           |
    |       .         |
    |         A       |
    |           .     |
    v             .   v
GARMENTS            STEADIER
    |     .           |
    |       .         |
    |         M       |
    |           .     |
    v             .   v
STRANGE             DIAMETERS
    |             .   |
    |           .     |
    |         D       |
    |       .         |
    v     .           v
GRANDEST            STEAMIER
    |             .   |
    |           .     |
    |         I       |
    |       .         |
    v     .           v
GRADIENTS           STEAMER
    |             .   |
    |           .     |
    |         E       |
    |       .         |
    v     .           v
DENIGRATES          MASTER
```

Notice that at each step, you may transfer in either direction.  You are not obligated to alternate between right to left and left to right.

---

**Afterword:**

Here is another solution using more familiar words:

> `INSANE        RETROSPECT`
>         `CANINES        PROTESTER`
>         `CRANNIES        TREETOPS`
>         `CANNERIES        PROTEST`
>         `NECTARINES        POSTER`
>         `ENTRANCES        RIPOSTE`
>         `REENACTS        PROTEINS`
>         `EASTERN        INSPECTOR`
>         `ASTERN        RECEPTIONS`
>         `SENATOR        PRESCIENT`
>         `REASON        INTERCEPTS`
>         `PERSONA        INTERSECT`
>         `PERSON        INTERCASTE`
>         `OPENERS        INTERACTS`
>         `PIONEERS        TRANSECT`
>         `INTERPOSE        TRANCES`
>         `PROTEINS        REENACTS`
>         `RIPOSTE        ENTRANCES`
>         `POSTER        NECTARINES`
>         `PROTEST        CANNERIES`
>         `TREETOPS        CRANNIES`
>         `PROTESTER        CANINES`
>         `RETROSPECT        INSANE`

Comment: Pennywise.....?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Amazing puzzle! Found a solution after a couple of hours of hunting (I hope that all the words I used are allowed in this puzzle)

> ```
>      INSANE             RETROSPECT
>
>         |             .   |
>
>         |           .     |
>
>         |         T       |
>
>         |       .         |
>
>         v     .           v
>
>      INANEST            RECEPTORS
>
>         |             .   |
>
>         |           .     |
>
>         |         C       |
>
>         |       .         |
>
>         v     .           v
>
>      INSTANCE           REPOSTER
>
>         |             .   |
>
>         |           .     |
>
>         |         E       |
>
>         |       .         |
>
>         v     .           v
>
>     TENANCIES           REPORTS
>
>         |             .   |
>
>         |           .     |
>
>         |         T       |
>
>         |       .         |
>
>         v     .           v
>
>     ANCIENTEST          PROSER
>
>         |             .   |
>
>         |           .     |
>
>         |         R       |
>
>         |       .         |
>
>         v     .           v
>
>     INTERSECANT         PROSE
>
>         |     .           |
>
>         |       .         |
>
>         |         N       |
>
>         |           .     |
>
>         v             .   v
>
>     INTERCASTE          PERSON
>
>         |     .           |
>
>         |       .         |
>
>         |         A       |
>
>         |           .     |
>
>         v             .   v
>
>     INTERSECT           PERSONA
>
>         |     .           |
>
>         |       .         |
>
>         |         T       |
>
>         |           .     |
>
>         v             .   v
>
>     ENTICERS            OPERANTS
>
>         |             .   |
>
>         |           .     |
>
>         |         O       |
>
>         |       .         |
>
>         v     .           v
>
>     RESECTION           PARENTS
>
>         |     .           |
>
>         |       .         |
>
>         |         I       |
>
>         |           .     |
>
>         v             .   v
>
>     TENSCORE            PAINTERS
>
>         |             .   |
>
>         |           .     |
>
>         |         P       |
>
>         |       .         |
>
>         v     .           v
>
>     COPRESENT           RETAINS
>
>         |             .   |
>
>         |           .     |
>
>         |         R       |
>
>         |       .         |
>
>         v     .           v
>
>     PRECENTORS          TINEAS
>
>         |     .           |
>
>         |       .         |
>
>         |         N       |
>
>         |           .     |
>
>         v             .   v
>
>     RECEPTORS           INANEST
>
>         |             .   |
>
>         |           .     |
>
>         |         T       |
>
>         |       .         |
>
>         v     .           v
>
>     RETROSPECT          INSANE
> ```

Comment: Wow, wow!  You definitely solved it!  Great work.  All of your steps are correct, and I have confirmed that all of these are in fact English words.  And, I really built my vocabulary today!  Not only did I have to reach for my dictionary, but some of these are not even in my dictionary!  In case you're interested, there exists another path using more common words.  If no one can find it by tomorrow, I will present it.

Comment: BTW, in the step immediately prior to INTERCASTE, you show an "S" being transferred, but I think you meant it to be an "N".

Comment: Thank you very much for confirming! :D